# questions regarding JVM specification on Threads and Locks

Tags: concurrency, jvm

In the [JVM spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se6/html/Threads.doc.html)

> When data is copied from the main memory to a working memory, two
> actions must occur: a read operation performed by the main memory,
> followed some time later by a corresponding load operation performed
> by the working memory.

Must read and load operation happen back to back? Can there be other machine instructions between read and load? In a read operation it only says where to read data from, but it does not say where to keep the data. So if there are other machine instructions between read and load, where is the data kept during the process between the two operations?

> A lock action (by a thread tightly synchronized with main memory)
> causes a thread to acquire one claim on a particular lock. An unlock
> action (by a thread tightly synchronized with main memory) causes a
> thread to release one claim on a particular lock.

What is the relation of the lock/unlock specified here and the lock/unlock implemented in synchronized keyword and locks in the JUC library? How the lock mentioned in the spec is implemented? Is it implemented by some machine instructions or by setting a mark on a variable header?

Comment: Perhaps you can focus this set of questions down to just one?

Comment: [Same answer as to your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72432572/2711488). Do not try to reason about the JVM based on an utterly outdated specification.